# Differentiate between dynamic and manually assigned array keys

Tags: php, arrays, key

I was looking for a way to shorten my code, and could not find the answer to this question.

In this sample array:

```
$addressData = array(
    'Full Name',
    'Address Line 1',
    'Address Line 2',
    30 => 'City/Town',
    22 => 'Province/State/Region',
    27 => 'Postal/ZIP code',
    'Country',
);
```

The first three values will be assigned keys 0, 1, and 2, respectively. The last value (Country) will be assigned key 31.

When I walk through this array, is there any way that I can treat those manually assigned values in different manner than the automatically assigned values?

I can't find anything in the manual, but I thought the community might be able to help.

**Edit for further clarification.** This is not real code, but it explains what I hope to achieve:

```
foreach($addressData as $key => $value){
    if(is_set_manually($key)){
        $someValue = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correction: the last key actually becomes 31. I double-checked.

Comment: You'll have to build some custom logic which checks for the key's sequence and if the sequence is broken then `/* add code here */`

Comment: What does this even mean? _treat those manually assigned values in different manner than the automatically assigned values?_

Comment: Anyways, there's no magical PHP bullet which will tell you which key was designated manually versus which one was simply a sequential continuation. Think of all PHP arrays as always being associative and sometimes they happen to be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand your question correctly, but if you want to fix sequence if it's broken you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$addressData = array(
    'Full Name',
    'Address Line 1',
    'Address Line 2',
    30 => 'City/Town',
    22 => 'Province/State/Region',
    27 => 'Postal/ZIP code',
    'Country',
);
$result= [];
$first = 0;
foreach($addressData as $key=>$data){      
    if($key != $first && ($key > $first+1)){
        $newkey = $first;
        $result[$newkey] = $data;
    }else{
         $result[$key] = $data;
    }
    $first++;
}
print_r($result);
```

And new array `$result` looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Full Name
    [1] => Address Line 1
    [2] => Address Line 2
    [3] => City/Town
    [4] => Province/State/Region
    [5] => Postal/ZIP code
    [6] => Country
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can assign array like following format may be helpful for your answer.

```
<?php
$addressData = array(
    'Full Name',
    'Address Line 1',
    'Address Line 2',
    array(30 => 'City/Town'),
    array(22 => 'Province/State/Region'),
    array(27 => 'Postal/ZIP code'),
    'Country',
);

foreach($addressData as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        echo 'Manually Key<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'Dynamic Key<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Right. This is more or less what I'm trying to avoid, in order to save a walk through a multidimensional array. A few people have confused my meaning, so I will edit in a simple bit of code to help explain.